# why my appinsight query gives me random result?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

This is my appinsight query. Basically I have a monitor program runs every 15 minutes and log a matrix of data. I want to compare **latest matrix against previous matrix** and **latest matrix against prePrevious matrix**, and create an warning only when both compare shows a jump (e.g. 20%)

```
//get the requests I am interested in first
 let allRequest=requests
    | where operation_Name == "SearchServiceFieldMonitor" and timestamp > ago(4h)
    | extend IndexerMismatch = tostring(customDimensions.IndexerMismatch)
    | extend Mismatch = split(IndexerMismatch, " in ")
    | extend    difference = toint(Mismatch[0])
            ,   field = tostring(Mismatch[1])
            ,   indexer = tostring(Mismatch[2])
            ,   index = tostring(Mismatch[3])
            ,   service = tostring(Mismatch[4])
            ,   timestamp
|project field, indexer,index,service, timestamp,difference;

//get the latest requests
let latestRequest=allRequest
|summarize  latesttime=arg_max(timestamp, *) by field, indexer,index,service
|project latestdifference=difference,latesttime,field, indexer,index,service;

//get the requests before latest (latest-1)
let previousRequest=allRequest 
|join latestRequest on  field, indexer,index,service
|extend timestampcopy=timestamp
|where timestamp<latesttime
|summarize  previousdifftime=arg_max(timestamp, *) by field, indexer,index,service
|project latestdifference,previousdifference=difference,previousdifftime,latesttime,field, indexer,index,service;

//get the requests before latest-1, so latest-2
let beforepreviousRequest=allRequest 
|join previousRequest on  field, indexer,index,service
|where timestamp<previousdifftime
|summarize  prevPrevtime=arg_max(timestamp, *) by field, indexer,index,service
|project latestdifference,previousdifference,prevprevdifference=difference,prevPrevtime,previousdifftime,latesttime,field, indexer,index,service;

// show requests that there is a jump of difference between latest and (latest-1) and latest and (latest-1)
beforepreviousRequest
|where (latestdifference -previousdifference)/previousdifference>0.2 and (latestdifference -prevprevdifference)/prevprevdifference>0.2
```

However, this query gives random results. If I click the run button a couple of times, it could show 0 record, 1 record or a couple of records. Is there something wrong with the join I am using or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default [join kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) is "innerunique" which returns only one row (can be any row) from the left side. Change the kind to "inner" or any other kind to get consistent results.

Comment: maybe that is the problem. I changed to a leftjoin and seems get much more stable results now